# Connect to rabbitmq from StreamAnalytix

Tags: python, rabbitmq, streamanalytix

I'm trying out [StreamAnalytix](https://www.streamanalytix.com/), one of the things I want to do is to read data rabbitmq, for that I'm using the service [cloudamqp](https://www.cloudamqp.com/), I tested it first using python only, but now that I´m trying to consume data from  StreamAnalytix  I'm not finding the right parameters.

This is what StreamAnalytix  ask for:

[image]

But I do not see where  to get those parameters. From Python I only need and url to send and consume data, I followed [this](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/python.html) sample code:

publish.py

```
import pika, os

# Access the CLODUAMQP_URL environment variable and parse it (fallback to localhost)
url = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f')
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello') # Declare a queue
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello CloudAMQP!')

print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

consume.py

```
# 
import pika, os

# Access the CLODUAMQP_URL environment variable and parse it (fallback to localhost)
url = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f')
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello') # Declare a queue
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
  print(" [x] Received " + str(body))

channel.basic_consume('hello',
                      callback,
                      auto_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages:')
channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```

For that case I only need the CLOUDAMQP_URL, that I get from my acount:

[image]

I saw from the documentation that the  parameters: routing_key, exchange and exchange_type can be set from python as:

```
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello') # Declare a queue
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='pressure', exchange_type='fanout')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='pressure',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello CloudAMQP!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

But just setting:

routing_key = hello

exchange  = pressure

exchange_type = fanout

in StreamAnalytix  does not work, since date data of the URL is not there.

Which parameters from cloudamqp should I look for, to stablish the conecction to streamanalytix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the implementation details StreamAnalytix, but it sounds like that app is expecting the exchange, queue, and binding to already exist on the RabbitMQ cluster.

So, I would suggest logging into the RabbitMQ web manager and configuring these items.  Make sure that you add a binding from the exchange to the queue that uses the desired routing key.

Then try running your application again.